# Best way to remove excess solder from sweat fittings for re-use?

Tags: plumbing, soldering, reuse

I’m disassembling and reconfiguring part of my hydronic heating system and I want to re-use several high quality 1” brass sweat-connected ball valves that would cost about $30 each to replace. (I have more time than money.) The heating system is about 15 years old but the valves are in good shape. They were originally assembled with lead solder.

I’ve already reclaimed one of them after removal by reheating the cup till the solder melts, then wiping inside the cup with a wad of fine steel wool, which seems to attract excess solder pretty well and leaves a smooth surface that will accept a piece of new pipe without interference. I’m protecting the valve body from overheating with wet rags.

Is there a better way? Something that works better than steel wool? Add a little flux? Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not certain if it will work for lead solder for plumbing, but for electronics, solder-wick is used to get rid of it when desoldering parts.

Comment: @FreeMan A good thought but not practical due to the large size of plumbing fittings vs the tiny size of PCB solder pads.

Comment: Hence a comment, not an answer... ;)

Comment: They make pretty big solder wick.

Comment: When I first saw the title I assumed you were looking to re-use the solder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing is what I've found to be most effective also.  Don't add any flux to the fittings, however, add some to the steel wool since you want the solder to cling to it and not the pipe fittings.

Keep in mind that you're not going to want to reuse these for any sort of drinking water use since they were originally soldered with lead-based solder and it's nearly impossible to get it all off.  But for your heating system use or other non-potable water use, no problem as long as they are in good shape.

Comment: Yes, these are all for re-use in the heating system, good point.

Comment: Microscopic amounts of lead won’t hurt. It’s lead, not plutonium.

Comment: Steel wool + flux *is* solder wick, just made of steel instead of copper.

Comment: love your comment Harp!  Let's not over-react to a tiny bit of lead.   Reacting to another comment:   I thought flux was to prevent oxidation of the copper while heating so I see no need to use it when cleaning up previously soldered fittings.  I think what the OP is doing using steel wool is about as good as it gets.

Comment: Thank you Harper. People don't realize how many lead joints and possibly even lead pipes their water has passed through before it gets to their home. And no-one died.

Comment: Let's not forget that -- real hazard or not -- when it's time to sell your home, a buyer's home inspector can readily test for the presence of lead on a soldered pipe connection, and if you have a skittish buyer they can walk away from a deal that's already in contract. Once this is on the record, your real estate agent must disclose the "defect" to all subsequent buyers. It's just not worth the risk unless you plan to live in your house until you die and leave no heirs.